# Whatsapp Business initiated message not received by end-user (edge case)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I am using Whatsapp's Business API through Meta's Graph API.
One of my end user claimed he didn't receive a **business-initiated message** however on my end I received (through webhooks) both **sent** and **delivered** confirmation.

I then gave him the chatbot's number and when he tried to send a text, he was prompted to accept Whatsapp's Chatbot Privacy Policy (or something like that).

So are we not able to start **business-initiated conversations** to users that never had prior interaction with a chatbot?

Comment: Unless the user initiated the conversion from their end, I think you always need to make them opt-in first? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview/getting-opt-in

Comment: @CBroe, users are opted-in via an external service. The problem here is that  Whatsapp does not display the "Accept Policy" popup for business-initiated conversation.